# Only 1 custom metabox open at a time

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have custom metaboxes each have the classes '.postbox .acf-postbox', when closed they get the class '.closed'.

To have them all closed by default I have:
$('.postbox.acf-postbox').addClass('closed');

But what I need is to only have one open at a time. So start with the first metabox open and the others closed, if I open another one it must auto-close the current metabox and open the clicked one.

The issue is they all have the same class so I am unsure how to target the active one so I can close the others.

edit:
Managed to add dynamic ID's so if I use:

```
$('.postbox.acf-postbox').click( function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

I am able to view the metabox ID, so I just need to close the metaboxes that do not have the clicked ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noob question, solved it by simply:

```
$('.postbox.acf-postbox').click( function(){
    $('.postbox.acf-postbox').addClass('closed');
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
});
```